# Simplify a formula for row value

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to  get sum of a row value .

```
=((Attendance!$C$3*Attendance!C5))+ ((Attendance!$D$3*Attendance!D5))+((Attendance!$E$3*Attendance!E5))+((Attendance!$f$3*Attendance!f5))+ ((Attendance!$g$3*Attendance!g5))+((Attendance!$h$3*Attendance!h5))+((Attendance!$i$3*Attendance!i5))+ ((Attendance!$j$3*Attendance!j5))+((Attendance!$k$3*Attendance!k5))+((Attendance!$l$3*Attendance!l5))+ ((Attendance!$m$3*Attendance!m5))+((Attendance!$n$3*Attendance!n5))
```

The column number  needs to be on 3  for parameter , and column 5 for second one. I like to do for next 10 more columns, Is there a simple formula to achieve the result

Answer (score 0):

this should do the work more in more simple way: 
=SUMPRODUCT(Attendance!$C$3:$N$3, Attendance!C5:N5)
Than just copy paste to other columns you need

Comment: Need to multiply c3  with c5 , --- n3 with n5

Comment: Yeah, this makes it. This formula multiplies c3*c5 + d3*d5 + ... + n3*n5.